# Power Amplifier inside an OPAMP

Tags: operational-amplifier, fet, power-amplifier

Here is a simplified schematic diagram of one of the operational amplifiers inside a TL08x.

[The Diagram](https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/quiz/00800x01.png)

I wonder why a power amplifier is used ? (on the right side) What is it good for ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that is a "power amplifier" ? Suppose it runs on 1 mA quiescent current and can only deliver 10 mA to the output, would you still call that a "power amplifier"? Opamp designer simply call it an '"output stage", so have a guess what it is for.

Comment: You use a power amplifier if you want to get much power out of it. But the TL08x is no [OPA549](http://www.ti.com/product/OPA549), so why do you call it that?

Answer (score 2):

To keep the quiescent current low, the left hand transistors run at a low current, usually <1mA.

To provide usable output current, usually >20mA, to drive the load and feedback resistors, the right hand transistors provide current gain. That's not a 'power amplifier', but you do see that sort of transistor arrangement on the outputs of power amplifiers.